# How do I filter a free text column in a MOSS 2007 list?

Tags: list, filter, form

I want to add a filter to a list I have created. When I use a form filter I don't get the option of filtering by any of the columns that are multiline text columns. Basically I have an A-Z. The first column being title (which I can set up a form filter for) and the second column is description. I want users to add a word into a filter box which would then interrogate the description column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in SharePoint query string filters appending this to the Form URL

```
?FilterName=[YourDescriptionField]&FilterMultiValue=*[SearchText]*
```